# Change a text in textbox with JavaScript "this"?

Tags: javascript, forms, this

I would like to change the text in the textbox id="1" when different radio buttons are focused. I thought it would work with "this.value" but somehow it dosn't. Has someone any idea how to solve this?

Regards!

```
   <head>
     <title>Test</title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var a = function(){

            if(this.value == "p"){

                document.getElementById("1").value = "Question product";

            }
            else if(this.value== "v"){

                document.getElementById("1").value = "Question contract";

            }

            else if(this.value== "t"){

                document.getElementById("1").value = "Question technology";

            }

        }
     </script>

   </head>

   <body>
     <input type="radio" name="typ" value="p" onfocus="a()"/> product
     <input type="radio" name="typ" value="v" onfocus="a()"/> contract 
     <input type="radio" name="typ" value="t" onfocus="a()"/> technology 
     <br />
     <input type="text" value="Question" size="46" id="1"/>
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pass `this` as a parameter for the function. Otherwise, you're grabbing the global object.

Comment: hey, i know how to use jquery there it is no problem. But I've to do this via JavaScript :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use focus but onclick and please use an array and give the field an ID beginning with a letter or underscore

```
<head>
     <title>Test</title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      var questionDescription={
        p:"Question product",
        v:"Question contract",
        t:"Question technology"
      }
      window.onload=function(){
        var typ=document.getElementsByName("typ");
        for (var i=0,n=typ.length;i<n;i++) {
          typ[i].onclick=function() {
            document.getElementById("q1").value=questionDescription[this.value]
          }
        }
     }
     </script>

   </head>

   <body>
     <input type="radio" name="typ" value="p" /> product
     <input type="radio" name="typ" value="v" /> contract 
     <input type="radio" name="typ" value="t" /> technology 
     <br />
     <input type="text" value="Question" size="46" id="q1"/>
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: +1 That's the way to go... IE has some issues with `getElementsByName` though afaik.

Comment: What would that be? Do you have an example? If it is an issue, just wrap the radios in a form and do `var typ=document.forms[0].typ;`

Comment: Nothing too bad. It seems IE is also considering elements where the **id** has this value (http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t125).

Answer (score 1):

```
input type="radio" name="typ" value="p" onfocus="a(this)"/> product
```

You need to pass this in as an argument first, then do

```
var a = function(obj){

        if(obj.value == "p"){

            document.getElementById("1").value = "Question product";

        }
        else if(obj.value== "v"){

            document.getElementById("1").value = "Question contract";

        }

        else if(obj.value== "t"){

            document.getElementById("1").value = "Question technology";

        }
```

instead